# Trouble sorting shape objects into several array-lists depending on shape parameters

Tags: java

My objective is to sort shapes into sheets > shelf objects depending on the parameters of each randomly generated shape. Each sheet can contain as many shelves as necessary depending on sheet parameters. The max width is (SHEET_WIDTH) and max height is (SHEET+HEIGHT). When the with is too high but there is enough height, a new shelf is generated within the sheet object. Each sheet and shelf is tracked by an index.

My problem is that all shapes are being stored within the same shelf on the first sheet. I've manually gone through each statement and cannot find a resolution.

```
public List<Sheet> nextFit(List<Shape> shapes) {

    List<Sheet> usedSheets = new ArrayList<Sheet>();
    int sheetIndex = 0;
    int shelfIndex = 0;
    Sheet firstSheet = new Sheet();
    Shelf firstShelf = new Shelf();
    firstSheet.addShelf(firstShelf);
    usedSheets.add(firstSheet);

    Sheet currentSheet = usedSheets.get(sheetIndex);
    Shelf currentShelf = currentSheet.getShelves().get(shelfIndex);
     // usedsheets(0)(depending on index)(get shelf



    for (Shape s: shapes) {

        if (s.getWidth() <= Sheet.SHEET_WIDTH - currentShelf.getWidth()
                && s.getHeight() <= Sheet.SHEET_HEIGHT - currentSheet.allShelvesHeight()) {
            currentShelf.place(s);
        } else if (s.getWidth() > Sheet.SHEET_WIDTH - currentShelf.getWidth()
                && s.getHeight() <= Sheet.SHEET_HEIGHT - currentSheet.allShelvesHeight()) {
            Shelf nextShelf = new Shelf();
            currentSheet.addShelf(nextShelf);
            shelfIndex++;
            currentShelf.place(s);

        } else if (s.getHeight() > Sheet.SHEET_HEIGHT - currentSheet.allShelvesHeight()) { 
            Sheet newSheet = new Sheet();
            Shelf newShelf = new Shelf();
            newSheet.addShelf(newShelf);
            usedSheets.add(newSheet);
            sheetIndex++;
            shelfIndex = 0;
            currentShelf.place(s);

        }

    }

    return usedSheets;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never change currentShelf when you create a new Shelf object

```
currentSheet.addShelf(nextShelf);
shelfIndex++;
currentShelf = nextShelf;
currentShelf.place(s);
```

And you have the same problem when you create a new sheet with both currentSheet and currentShelf

Comment: Sorry if I'm being unclear, but the currentShelf uses shelfIndex to grab the 2nd shelf object from my list so I wouldn't have to declare it manually. Although the implementation might be incorrect. I tried your edit but it yields the same result. edit(i tried again and your implementation does work)

Comment: @Cotchsloth So your issue is resolved or did I misunderstand the last edit to your comment?